# css - create a circle at the bottom right position of an element

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to come up with a system where I can easily place a small circle at the top left and bottom right of a container element - an element that will be dynamic in size using flex or grid etc.

I managed to get the top-left circle appearing in the right place (`c-tl`) but I can't figure out how to get the bottom-right circle appearing at the other end of the border line.

I've tried messing around with different display types on different elements (e.g. the blue circle) and `::after` selectors on various elements (e.g. the orange circle)... I'm sure there's an easy way but I'm certainly not a css expert!

```css
.container {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 2rem;
}

.ele {
    padding: 2rem;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 1rem;
    border-left: solid 1px grey;
    border-bottom: solid 1px grey;
}

.c-tl {
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    border-radius:5px;
    background-color: grey;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    top: 5px;
    left: -5px;
}

.c-br {
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    border-radius:5px;
    background-color: orange;
    display: block;
}

.ele::after{
  content: "";
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    border-radius:5px;
    background-color: blue;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <span class="c-tl"></span>
    <div class="ele">
        <p>Hello, world!</p>
    </div>
    <span class="c-br"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `position: absolute;` with `bottom: 0;` and `right: 0;` to position the desired element on the bottom right corner of its parent element which must have `position: relative;`.

In your case:

- the `.c-tl` and `.c-br` must be placed in `.ele` (the element relative which the circles are placed)
- add `position: relative;` to `.ele`
- add `position: absolute;` to both  `.c-tl` and `.c-br`, and their corresponding `top`/`bottom` & `left`/`right` values set.

[Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp) (last example)

```css
.container {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 2rem;
}

.ele {
    padding: 2rem;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 1rem;
    border-left: solid 1px grey;
    border-bottom: solid 1px grey;
    position: relative;
}

.c-tl {
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    border-radius:5px;
    background-color: grey;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: -5px;
    left: -5px;
}

.c-br {
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    border-radius:5px;
    background-color: orange;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -5px;
    right: -5px;
}

.ele::after{
  content: "";
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    border-radius:5px;
    background-color: blue;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="ele">
        <span class="c-tl"></span>
        <p>Hello, world!</p>
        <span class="c-br"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The orange circle does not appear in the right place in that it is not centered on the line, but more problematically it appears at the bottom of the screen if you go to full page snippet.

Comment: @AHaworth thank you for pointing that out. Edited post should fix that issue.

Comment: Oh so "absolute" with a parent "relative" will get its absolute position from that parent?! I had no idea, I always thought absolute was just referencing the entire screen!! Thanks!

Comment: @jamheadart not gonna lie, I thought similarly. The reference material helped me formulate the answer)

Answer (score 1):

I added the following to your `c-br` class.

```css
float: right;
position: relative;
top: -5px;
right: -5px;
```

It seems to work in both views, including full screen.

```css
.container {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 2rem;
}

.ele {
  padding: 2rem;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 1rem;
  border-left: solid 1px grey;
  border-bottom: solid 1px grey;
}

.c-tl {
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: grey;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: 5px;
  left: -5px;
}

.c-br {
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: orange;
  display: block;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  top: -5px;
  right: -5px;
}

.ele::after {
  content: "";
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: blue;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span class="c-tl"></span>
  <div class="ele">
    <p>Hello, world!</p>
  </div>
  <span class="c-br"></span>
</div>
```